# My phantom cup doesn't have the same width as my non-phantom cups in an align environment; how can I fix this?

Tags: align

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Q= & \phantom{\cup} \{\{n-1,n-1,3\}\} \\
   & \cup \{\{n-1,n-j+1,j+1\}: 3 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor\} \\
   & \cup \{\{n-2,n-j+1,j+2\}: 4 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor-1\}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want the brackets to line up on the left, but it's not behaving.  How can I nudge the first bracket to the left to align with the other brackets?

It lines up properly if we don't use a `\phantom{\cup}`, but I don't actually want the cup there.

Comment: `\mathbin{\phantom{\cup}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this will suit.  In the first example, I set the alignment point after the `\cup`, whereas in the second, I set it after the `=` sign.

When things like `\cup` and `=` are surrounded by math atoms, additional space is provided as separation.  Such space is, for example, not present when those glyphs stand alone as in `$=$`.  The problem with `\phantom` is that it loses track of what surrounds it.  Thus, the method of using `{}\cup{}` is a way to designate using `\cup` as if something (in this case two empty groups) surrounds it on both sides.  In that case, the extra space is inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
Q = \phantom{{}\cup{}}& \{\{n-1,n-1,3\}\} \\
   \phantom{=} \cup{}& \{\{n-1,n-j+1,j+1\}: 3 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor\} \\
   \phantom{=} \cup{}& \{\{n-2,n-j+1,j+2\}: 4 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor-1\}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, this would suffice:

```
\begin{align*}
Q={} & \phantom{{}\cup{}} \{\{n-1,n-1,3\}\} \\
   & \cup \{\{n-1,n-j+1,j+1\}: 3 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor\} \\
   & \cup \{\{n-2,n-j+1,j+2\}: 4 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor-1\}.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: For the uninitiated, you may want to explain in words what `\phantom{{}\cup{}}` achieves that `\phantom{\cup}` does not. Put differenty, what do the empty groups, `{}`, that you've placed around `\cup` "do"?